# Find rotation matrix with two vectors

Tags: matlab, matrix, rotation

I want to find the rotation matrix between two vectors.

```
[0;0;1] = R * [0.0023;0.0019;0.9899]
```

How do I find the 3*3 rotation matrix?

Comment: @ZizyArcher What do you mean? Both vectors are 3 elements...

Comment: @ZizyArcher I'd advise using the words "magnitude" or "norm" when talking about vector *lengths* in a programming context, otherwise your comments can easily be confusing. The length of a vector here would usually be an attribute of the array's size; in MATLAB the `length` of a vector is the number of elements. Note also that the example given by the OP could be subject to rounding (1 is pretty close to 0.98), so it would be more useful to note something like "be aware that the magnitude of the vectors is different, if this isn't due to rounding then the rotation matrix is ill-defined".

Comment: @Wolfie I see how my poor choice of words led to confusion. I can't seem to edit my comments anymore unfortunately, so I deleted them.

Though difference of 0.98 vs 1 is large enough it cannot be due to rounding unless there were many steps. The only possibility is that the last element is actually 0.9999.

Comment: Also related and a solution to get the actual rotation matrix: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180418/calculate-rotation-matrix-to-align-vector-a-to-vector-b-in-3d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple rearrangement

```
% [0;0;1] = R * [0.0023;0.0019;0.9899];
% So ...
% [0;0;1] / [0.0023;0.0019;0.9899] = R
% This is a valid MATLAB command

R = [0;0;1] / [0.0023;0.0019;0.9899];
>> R =
    [ 0    0    0
      0    0    0
      0    0    1.0102 ]
```

We can validate this result

```
R * [0.0023;0.0019;0.9899]
>> ans =
    [0; 0; 1]
```

Comment: It has to be pointed out that the / operator puts as many zeros as possible in such ill-defined cases. There are infinitely many other solutions for the rotation matrix. (which doesn't exist in the strictest sense, as vector norm is not preserved in the example).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be defined as a linear equation, say,

```
y = mx
```

where, `y` and `x` are matrices. Find `m`.

Solution:

```
m = x\y or m = mldivide(x,y)
```

Notice the `backslash`. It is not a forward slash `/` as ***Wolfie*** mentioned in his answer. For details see https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html

**Additional Details:**

If `x` is a singular matrix, use `pinv`. See https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pinv.html for reference.